# How can I store my saves in the cloud?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360, xbox-network

Is there a way to enable the cloud storage option for Skyrim saves? Other games ask me where I want my save file.

Comment: Just an FYI, if you save often (You do save often, right? it is a Bethesda game after all), you will use up your 512MB fairly quickly unless you clean up your old saves manually. I'm a ways in and each save is 9MB in size.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, in your system preferences, go to storage, and move the save file over there. When you load the game it will ask what storage device to use. Select "Cloud Storage" and it will use that.

Comment: oh wow, I can do that? ok. I'm still getting used to the new system. thanks! I'll give that a go. I've been playing on a variety of systems/places due to a bad tv.

Comment: Sorry what "system preferences" do you mean?

Comment: @wired00 don't recall offhand, but if you go to your xbox settings select "System Preferences" It may have renamed in an update since then. What you are looking for is a place to mange your storage

Comment: Ahh right no wonder. I completely misread the OP i thought it was regarding Steam Save games :) thanks for quick response anyways

Comment: CAUTION. I've done this before with my bioshock data and it didn't save a single thing to the cloud OR my friends hard drive when I played at his house. Lost all of my game. I don't know why I did it but I haven't trusted the cloud since.